# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found ( Str method doesn't work )

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

i am trying to conclude the unfinished module, but i'm having major problem which i can't find fix for, Also note, that i am doing this in Python2. Full code is [here](https://github.com/GTB3NW/SteamTradingServices/blob/master/Exchange/exchange.py).

When the code was executed, the first problem i got was in line 69:

Full Log:

```
>>> main()
INFO:Exchange.exchange:Exchange Service is starting
INFO:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5672
INFO:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Created channel=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-6.6-py2.7.egg/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-6.6-py2.7.egg/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-6.6-py2.7.egg/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-6.6-py2.7.egg/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exchange/exchange.py", line 38, in main
    Exchange(rmqhost, redishost, redisport, redisdb, status, publishresult).consume()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exchange/exchange.py", line 69, in __init__
    log.debug("Connecting to redis on " + self.redishost + ":" + self.redisport + " db: " + self.redisdb)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

So i tried converting it to unicode string:

```
    log.debug("Connecting to redis on " + str(self.redishost) + ":" + str(self.redisport) + " db: " + str(self.redisdb))
```

But it gave me the same error on the same line:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exchange/exchange.py", line 69, in __init__
    log.debug("Connecting to redis on " + str(self.redishost) + ":" + str(self.redisport) + " db: " + str(self.redisdb))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

I also tried another way of converting string, but same error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exchange/exchange.py", line 69, in __init__
    log.debug("Connecting to redis on %s: %s db: %s",
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

---

What may the problem be? Even when i tried to covert it to the string it gave me the same error unfortunately... Do i need to import something from `__futre__` that would help the problem?

Comment: Can you add a traceback for the fixed code (i.e. with `str`s)?

Comment: I don't believe you get **the same** error when you convert to strings. Is it really the same?

Comment: Added the traceback when converting it to string.

Comment: did you try [`unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) instead of `str`?

Comment: @ShellRox, is it possible that you're still executing the old code, even though traceback shows you a new one?

Comment: I think @skovorodkin on a good trail... The error says that you are trying to do some operation (presumably `+`) with `unicode` and `int`, but the second version does not have an `int` at all.

Answer (score 2):

The *coercing* error happens when trying so do an operation with a unicode and something which cannot be automatically converted to unicode.

For example:

```
>>> u'something' + 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

On the other hand, with `unicode` and `str` it will work - `str` will coerce to `unicode` before applying the operation:

```
>>> u'something' + 'else'
u'somethingelse'
```

In the example, there are strings and variables (of unknown type), so it has to be that at least one of the variables was `unicode` and one an `int`, hence the *"coercing to Unicode"* error.

### General Solution

Any of these will work:

```
>>> u'aaaa ' + str(9) + ':' + str(15)
u'aaaa 9:15'
>>> u'aaaa %s: %s' % (9, 15)
u'aaaa 9: 15'
>>> u'aaaa {}: {}'.format(9, 15)
u'aaaa 9: 15'
```

### Logging Solution

The proper way to format logs would be:

```
log.debug("Connecting to redis on %s: %s db: %s",
          self.redishost,
          self.redisport,
          self.redisdb)
```

I.e. you do not format the string - you let the logger do that.

That way, you avoid formatting the strings if the log level is disabled.

It also looks much better.

Comment: Hello, i have mentioned that i have put it in str, but that would not work, after trying the logging solution, got the same error:  `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Exchange/exchange.py", line 69, in __init__
    log.debug("Connecting to redis on %s: %s db: %s",
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`

Comment: @ShellRox That is unexcpected... can you please try printing `repr((self.redishost,self.redisport,self.redisdb))` before this line? Also, add a few empty lines before this code, so that `line 69` contains something else. It is quite possible that you are running the old code which fails in line 69, but then the error displays current contents of that line. After moving the code, you will see whether the line number changes.

Comment: it returns `(u'127.0.0.1', 6379, 0)`.

Comment: It's actually fixed now, i think there was something wrong in system, restarting it helped.